# How to initiate Mathematica by double-clicking .nb file in Linux (with gnome desktop environment)?

Tags: linux

The user in which I installed the Mathematica is removed. There I could launch Mathematica by double-clicking its icon as well as any .nb file.

Now that I'm in a new user, for some reason the Mathematica icon is not even in the Application menu and double-clicking .nb file returns "Could not display 'xxx.nb'." and asks me to search **online** the software to link .nb file, which brings me nowhere.

I can still launch Mathematica via terminal command "math" or "mathematica" etc., but I wish I could just double-click launch from the desktop environment.

Debian 11 + gnome 3.38.6

Comment: Not sure this is related to Mathematica though. I suspect you'll have to somehow associate the nb extension to the appropriate program using your OS features.

Comment: Gnome wants you to install the *.desktop file for the application icon to appear.  An example .desktop file can be found in MMA 12 with `FileNames["wolfram-mathematic12.desktop", $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]`.  A copy of this file may be located elsewhere on your system.  The man pages for the desktop-file-install and the update-desktop-database programs may be helpful.

Comment: @LouisB Thanks, that worked easy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found and copied the file `wolfram-mathematica12.desktop` in the Mathematica installation directory `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.3/SystemFiles/Installation/` and simply pasted to `/usr/share/applications`. Problem solved!

Credit goes to [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/649915).